Unable to get the exact coordinates of a matched string from a PDF file to be signed electronically
I'm looking for a node.js solution in which the server will electronically sign PDF files and by tracing the coordinates of Signature field and I'm stuck here finding the right exact cooridnates of the singature field. The main challenge is tracing cooridnates because the signature filed could be at anywhere in the PDF document. I have tried pdf-parse, pdf-lib, PDFKIT and a few more libraries but ended up with failed solutions.
I also found the difference in coordinates space which totally makes sense but I didn't found a way to deal with this problem.

https://pspdfkit.com/guides/web/pspdfkit-for-web/coordinate-spaces/
Please let me knonw if you guys need more information from me about the problem. Thank you.
I tried a solution by subtracting page height with line number of the matched keyword but it also doesn't work. Maybe I my approach wasn't good to implement that's why I'm not so sure about that.

Thanks @KJ for responding. I figured it out. The best possible solution what I found is with pdf.js-extract package.
